# Should we always capitalize Christians, Muslims, etc.?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns

A christian and a jew went into a bar....

or

A Christian and a Jew went into a bar...

The former is marked incorrect by microsoft word.

Comment: In English the names of religions are proper names and hence capitalized.  (BTW, "Microsoft" and "Word" are also proper names.)

Comment: http://grammar.about.com/od/punctuationandmechanics/a/Guidelines-For-Using-Capital-Letters.htm

Answer (score 5):

You should always capitalize names for groups of religious people since they are proper nouns.